# Compute a new column as delta to another value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data frame:

```
     rank  cost brand city
0     1     1     a    x
1     2     2     a    x
2     3     3     a    x
3     4     4     a    x
4     5     5     a    x
5     1     2     b    y
6     2     4     b    y
7     3     6     b    y
8     4     8     b    y
9     5    10     b    y
```

I want to create a new column 'delta' which contains the cost difference compared to rank 1 for a certain brand-city combination.

Desired outcome:

```
     rank  cost brand city delta
0     1     1     a    x     0
1     2     2     a    x     1
2     3     3     a    x     2
3     4     4     a    x     3
4     5     5     a    x     4
5     1     2     b    y     0
6     2     4     b    y     2
7     3     6     b    y     4
8     4     8     b    y     6
9     5    10     b    y     8
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54712350/compute-delta-column-with-pandas) gave me some hints, but I am stuck on the fact that I cannot map a series to a multi-index.

To save on typing, here is some code:

```
data = {'rank': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
     'cost': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10],
     'brand': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
     'city': ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y'],
     'delta': ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '0', '2', '4', '6', '8']
     }
```

Answer (score 4):

This is `transform` + `first`

```
df['delta']=df.cost-df.groupby(['brand','city'])['cost'].transform('first')
df
Out[291]: 
   rank  cost brand city  delta
0     1     1     a    x      0
1     2     2     a    x      1
2     3     3     a    x      2
3     4     4     a    x      3
4     5     5     a    x      4
5     1     2     b    y      0
6     2     4     b    y      2
7     3     6     b    y      4
8     4     8     b    y      6
9     5    10     b    y      8
```

Comment: It seems that the rank mentioned in question refers to column `rank`. So `transform('first')` may not solve the problem in general.

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby` with `apply`

```
data['delta'] = (data.groupby(['brand', 'city'], group_keys=False)
                     .apply(lambda x: x['cost'] - x[x['rank'].eq(1)]['cost'].values[0]))

data

   rank  cost brand city delta
0     1     1     a    x     0
1     2     2     a    x     1
2     3     3     a    x     2
3     4     4     a    x     3
4     5     5     a    x     4
5     1     2     b    y     0
6     2     4     b    y     2
7     3     6     b    y     4
8     4     8     b    y     6
9     5    10     b    y     8
```

Answer (score 1):

solution without using `groupby`. it sorts `rank` and  uses `pd.merge_ordered` and `assign` to create `delta` column

```
In [1077]: pd.merge_ordered(data.sort_values(['brand', 'city', 'rank']), data.query('rank == 1'), how='left', on=['brand', 'city', 'rank'], fill_method='ffill').assign(delta=lambda x: x.cost_x - x.cost_y).drop('cost_y', 1)
Out[1077]:
  brand city  cost_x  rank  delta
0     a    x       1     1      0
1     a    x       2     2      1
2     a    x       3     3      2
3     a    x       4     4      3
4     a    x       5     5      4
5     b    y       2     1      0
6     b    y       4     2      2
7     b    y       6     3      4
8     b    y       8     4      6
9     b    y      10     5      8
```